# Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade stuck

Tags: software-installation, do-release-upgrade

Ubuntu beginner here. I tried upgrading last night from 20.04 to 22.04. But since the mirror is so slow, the download would take 1 day 15 hours so I left my laptop on overnight.

Now, it's stuck on the lockscreen (i guess it's still Fossa) and I can't enter my password. It won't budge.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you think the upgrade finished successfully overnight? Can you get to a tty? (Ctrl+Alt+F2) If you can get to a tty you can `sudo reboot` safely. Otherwise you may need to force shutdown the PC. If the upgrade failed, you may need to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks Nmath. I think it didnt finish :( Unfortunately I couldn't get to the terminal as it still is stuck on lockscreen. I tried it as you suggested. :( Looks like a fresh install huh

Comment: Thanks @Nmath a simple sudo reboot did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

This would have been easier if you had a faster network, this takes approximately 1-3 hours if internet if moderate.

To solve this,

1. all you have to do is get a fast internet,
2. turn on your computer, once booting start press right shift to open ubuntu recovery mode,
3. choose the latest kernel most prob is 5.13.x recovery mode.

> A new small window will pop

4. using arrow keys navigate to enable networking, ensure your Ethernet cable is working or use previous logged in wifi network.
5. Once set on step 4, select **dpkg**/**repair packages** and hit enter
6. All remaining packages will be continue to install.
7. To ensure 100% upgrade after process 6 is done, Run via root(Navigate using Arrow to drop root shell prompt)

   Sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade